# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string error

Tags: php, json, string, object

I have the following string:

```
{"Coords":[{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27770755361785","Longitude":"-9.011979642121824","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:09 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"}],"Scan":"Whatever"}
```

Which I want to decode in php. The string is obtained via a sql query. See code below:

```
$TrackDetails_Query= "SELECT * FROM Tracks WHERE TrackID='".$TrackNum."' ORDER BY TrackID DESC";

        $TrackDetails_Result= mysql_query($TrackDetails_Query) or die (mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($TrackDetails_Result)==0){
                echo 'There are no tracks for the number entered';
            }
        else{
                            $traces=$row['Traces'];
                            $decoded_traces=json_decode($traces);
                            echo $decoded_traces;
            }
    }
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Comment: What part of the `$decoded_traces` object are you expecting to see echoed?

Comment: The title of your question is misleading - I'd suggest changing it to "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question body?

Comment: What are you expecting `echo $decoded_traces;` to do, given it's the result of decoding the JSON?

Comment: @deceze I forgot to change the title much apologies! That was happening when I used 'encode' by accident as opposed to decode. I realised that and changed the question in the content but not the title.

Answer (score 29):

You get the error because you are trying to turn a stdClass object into a string, something it doesn't support.

Instead of `echo $decoded_traces` try `var_dump($decoded_traces)` - that will give a diagnostic view of the object you've decoded (which I presume is what you wanted). You should find it looks like this

```
class stdClass#1 (2) {
  public $Coords =>
  array(5) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#2 (4) {
      public $Accuracy =>
      string(2) "65"
      public $Latitude =>
      string(18) "53.277720488429026"
      public $Longitude =>
      string(18) "-9.012038778269686"
      public $Timestamp =>
      string(39) "Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    }
    [1] => (more of the same, edited for brevity)
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
    [4] =>
  }
  public $Scan =>
  string(8) "Whatever"
}
```

By default, [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_decode) will create stdClass objects like the above. If you would prefer an associative array, pass `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode`, e.g. `$decoded_traces=json_decode($traces, true);`

As a further aside, although stdClass can't be turned into a string, your own classes can - a class which implements the [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method could be converted to a string!

Answer (score 9):

use `json_encode($traces)` this will convert the array into the string. `json_decode()` is used to convert a string into array or object array

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
 $decoded_traces=json_decode($traces);
 echo $decoded_traces;
```

try

```
$decoded_traces=json_decode($traces, true);
print_r $decoded_traces;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using this
    `$decoded_traces=json_decode($traces, true);`

instead of this
    `$decoded_traces=json_decode($traces);`

It will convert your stdClass to array. Note that `$decoded_traces` is array then you can use as you require.

Answer (score 4):

It was an old question, still answer to make it clear for someone who just encounters it like me.

try json_encode($traces);

in my case

```
return var_dump(json_encode($result[0]));
```

the result is:

```
string(34) "{"id":1,"content":"test database"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`$decoded_traces` is an object. You cannot simply `echo` an object, because that makes no sense.

If you want to debug the object, use `var_dump($decoded_traces)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that it can happen in wordpress too if you are using the `$wpdb->get_row()` method and you miss adding the last parameter

You just need to add another parameter at the end of the [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/), so you'll get

`$res = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1" ,ARRAY_A)` which will output an array instead of an stdClass then you just have to use it like this

`$res['option_value']`