# How would I decode this JSON to insert into a json column? ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in file

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

What would be the proper way to decode this json?

my model has

```
 protected $casts = [
        'items' => 'array'
    ];
```

my json items:

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "name": "Google",
        "link": "http://google.com"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "ALink",
        "link": "http://link.org"
    }
  ]
}
```

`json_decode($request->items)` returns the error: `ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in file`

Comment: Take a look on this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17489801/2805538

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is of an object, not an array. You should cast it to an object like this

```
protected $casts = [
   'items' => 'object'
];
```

To save the json into your model you can then do `$obj->items = $request->items` after changing the cast to object as above.

Alternatively, If you have to save this as an array then you can cast the request into one by doing `(array)$request->items` instead of json_decode.

Comment: well when I query the field using this, it still returns as a string to js rather than a json object

Comment: I lied. I realized I just needed to encode the json field before sending off to the client. this answer works!